High PAPR (Peak-to-Average Power Ratio)
I have a signal $s(t)$ which has $PAPR=26$ dB. In the literature, the highest PAPR I have seen is OFDM with $PAPR_{ofdm} \simeq 12$ dB.
I would like to know if the PAPR (Peak-to-Average Power Ratio) for the $s(t)$ signal is too high to be used in practice?

It's very important to include the Complementary Cumulative Distribution Function (CCDF) when considering the peak-avg ratio for any waveform, otherwise any reported metric may not accurately reflect the distortion that may result. As Marcus points out, it is theoretically possible (and the OP  may have measured this case) to have a PAPR much higher than the 12 dB typically reported for OFDM. However the probability of this occurring for a random data stream is insignificant to effect any performance metric such as Error Vector Magnitude (EVM) or Out of Band Emissions (OOBE), the two typical requirements that are affected by amplifier non-linearity (which is ultimately why we care about PAPR).
Below is a graphic showing the typical CCDF for OFDM from this publication on CCDF from Lekhraj Udiagiriya and Sudhir Kumar Sharma which is consistent with my own experience with it. Note that the curve with the measurements crosses 0.001% here at around 10.5 dB. I discuss this further at this post where I show the results for OFDM waveforms of increasing sizes converging on a Gaussian distribution and exceeding 11.5 dB PAPR with 1e-6 probability. And there I also include the Python code that can be used to evaluate the CCDF and then properly report the PAPR.

The distribution in amplitude of uncompensated OFDM with random data follows very closely to a Gaussian given the central limit theorem (the time domain magnitude is the sum of multiple random variables corresponding to each bin in the DFT). 26 dB would correspond to $20\sigma$ which although possible, is extremely unlikely for the case of properly randomized data!
As for what is good enough, that is a system trade based on the power amplifier and any other non-linear components and the requirements for EVM and OOBE as mentioned. A waveform with a high PAPR such as OFDM requires greater back-off in power level from the 1 dB compression point for the power amplifier to reach the same performance as that for another waveform with less PAPR. This results in far less power efficiency (more DC power is required for a given transmit power), which is a dominant concern in battery operated devices and SATCOM systems. For that reason much is done to mitigate these effects while still using OFDM for all of its advantages. This includes selectively reducing the peaks in time ("Crest Factor Reduction" or CFR), and pre-distorting the waveform as such to exactly cancel the distortion due to the non-linearity ("Pre-distortion").

No, it's not. PAPRs of 400 (=26 dB) can happen to an OFDM system with significantly more than $\sqrt{400}=20$ carriers quite probably. Of course you'll build your coding such that these OFDM symbols are rare, but given you do that, have forward error correction, and quite capable ADCs these days, I don't see the problem. 12 or even 14 bit resolution (amplitude, power is the square!) on transmitter DACs are not a rarity these days.
Only reading literature that mentions 12 dB is not a good sign – you'll want to check up on how the PAPR in OFDM happens; in essence, it's just the DFT of vectors that are all constants or happen to look like an oscillation. That has a certain probability of happening if you allow for any combination of subcarrier constellation points.
